# Custom cursor alpha-channel turns black in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, browser, png, alpha

I have a custom cursor that works fine in most browsers. In firefox however, the parts that don't have 100% alpha turns black. As far as I can understand, Firefox is suppose to support alpha in cursor images.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG/Element/cursor

sample page(hoover the image):
http://dev.nuagency.se/illustrators/beata-boucht-2/

The image:
http://dev.nuagency.se/wp-content/themes/nuagency/images/left.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alpha-layers in cursors just was not supported in firefox, nothing to do about it.